# Fabric.js in React Context API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, fabricjs

Im creating a web app whereby a user drags and drops shapes onto a canvas. I am using fabric.js and React.

I'm trying to use fabric within the context api to make the canvas available across the app. I have found [this](https://github.com/saninmersion/react-context-fabricjs) repo which implements what I want and works correctly when I run their example.

I am using typescript but keep getting an error when I try to use the canvas from the context within my app.

I think the error is something to do with the `useState` but cant work out what is happening. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```js
// FabricContext.tsx
import React, { createContext, useCallback, useContext, useState } from "react";
import { fabric } from 'fabric'

interface IFabricContext {
  canvas: fabric.Canvas | null
  initCanvas: any
}

export const FabricContext = createContext<IFabricContext>({} as IFabricContext)

export const FabricContextProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const [canvas, setCanvas] = useState<fabric.Canvas | null>(null)

  const initCanvas = useCallback((el: HTMLCanvasElement, options: fabric.ICanvasOptions) => {
    const canvasOptions: fabric.ICanvasOptions = {
      ...options
    }
    let c = new fabric.Canvas(el, canvasOptions)
    c.renderAll()
    setCanvas(c)
  }, [])

  return (
    <FabricContext.Provider
      value={{ canvas, initCanvas }}
    >
      {children}
    </FabricContext.Provider>
  )
}

export const useFabricContext = (): IFabricContext => useContext(FabricContext)
```

```js
// Canvas.tsx
import { useLayoutEffect, useRef } from "react"
import { useFabricContext } from "../../context/FabricContext"

export default function Canvas(): JSX.Element {
  const canvasRef = useRef(null)
  const { initCanvas } = useFabricContext()

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    initCanvas(canvasRef.current, {
      width: 500,
      height: 500
    })
  }, [canvasRef, initCanvas])

  return (
    <canvas ref={canvasRef} style={{ border: "1px solid red" }} />
  )
}
```

```js
// App.tsx
import { fabric } from "fabric";
import Canvas from "./components/Canvas";
import { FabricContextProvider, useFabricContext } from "./context/FabricContext";

export default function AgilityCourseDesigner() {
  const { canvas } = useFabricContext()

  // Here is where I get the error
  // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')
  canvas!.add(new fabric.Circle({ top: 140, left: 230, radius: 75, fill: 'green' }))

  return (
    <FabricContextProvider>
      <Canvas />
    </FabricContextProvider>
  )
}
```

Comment: Don't use `!.` so silence an error. The point of TypeScript is that it will tell you the problem at compile time. Fix the code so it can't return undefined, or if it can, handle it correctly.

Comment: @ggorlen I have done that and get `TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'`. I think its something to do with the canvas not being added into the state in the `initCanvas` function but cant seem to work it out.

Comment: Your interface is typed `canvas: fabric.Canvas | null` so that's possibly null. If it's supposed to be null on the first render, maybe `canvas?.add` was your intent? Also, isn't the context provider supposed to be in a parent component?

Comment: @ggorlen the value of my context is an object so the destructing isnt the problem.